# Default group on Samsung Galxy S II does not sync with Gmail

Tags: contacts, sync, samsung-galaxy-s-2

The default groups on the Samsung Galaxy S II: Friends, Family and Co-Workers do not get sync with Google Contacts. Any thing I can do in order to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to your contacts - menu - more - display options? You should see your various accounts where there is an arrow to expand and check boxes for those particular groups (well, there is on mine! :-)